# How to fix: PyInstaller in MSYS2 MinGW 'Your platform is not yet supported'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, gtk3, msys2

I'm trying to package my GTK3+ Python 3 script using PyInstaller on Windows 10.

GTK3+ and the Python bindings are installed and working, using MSYS2 MinGW as per the GTK+ [instructions](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php).

In MSYS2 MinGW, when I type:

> pip3 install pyinstaller

I get the error:  Your platform is not yet supported. Please define constant PYDYLIB_NAMES for your platform.

So I attempted to install PyInstaller manually from Windows PowerShell by downloading and extracting the tar.gz file for PyInstaller and then running:

> python3 setup.py install

But with that, I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'".

How can I install PyInstaller in MinGW, for use on a GTK3+ Python3 script?

Answer (score 0):

You can download setuptools from PyPI and install manually with `python setup.py install`. Then repeat what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

With PyInstaller 3.6, you should no longer be getting the Your platform is not supported errors when trying to pip install it in MSYS2.