# Issues compiling GTK software in MSYS2/MinGW with PyInstaller

Tags: python, c, mingw, pyinstaller, msys2

I had a year old version of MSYS2/MinGW that was using PyInstaller with Python3.7 to compile a C GTK application in Windows (python was needed for a plotting script) and everything worked fine until pacman refused to update any packages since I kept getting the error:

```
error: hook /usr/share/libalpm/hooks/mingw-w64-x84_64-gtk-query-immodules-3.0.hook line 2: invalid value Path
error: hook /usr/share/libalpm/hooks/mingw-w64-x84_64-gtk-update-icon-cache.hook line 2: invalid value Path
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I looked those up and the general response for it is: "The issue is usually provoked when you don't maintain your system at regular intervals - and I am not thinking yearly - because such neglect will often result in similar problems. The issue stems from a change in pacman code..."

So I decided to start from a fresh MSYS2 install and used the following lines from both an MSYS2 shell and a MinGW-x64 shell, and each of them fails at a different point:

```
pacman -Syu
pacman -Su
pacman -S nano
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gtk3
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 mingw-w64-x86_64-python3 mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-gobject
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain git subversion mercurial mingw-w64-i686-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
pacman -S python3-pip
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-pip
pacman -S msys2-devel
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glade
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gobject-introspection
pip install pyinstaller
```

In the case of the MSYS2 shell, the `pip install pyinstaller` fails with:

```
# pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.exe /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpd9hk1ekp
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ouq11vnr/pyinstaller
  Complete output (1 lines):
  Your platform is not yet supported. Please define constant PYDYLIB_NAMES for your platform.
```

An internet search shows this issue coming up on the github page for PyInstaller and a post here, neither of which were remotely enlightening:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4542

[How to fix: PyInstaller in MSYS2 MinGW 'Your platform is not yet supported'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728231/how-to-fix-pyinstaller-in-msys2-mingw-your-platform-is-not-yet-supported)

In the case of a MinGW shell, I can install everything fine, but I cannot compile the C code because I get the error:

```
fatal error: sys/wait.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <sys/wait.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Which means that MinGW doesn't know where to look for this file. It is located in:

```
msys64/usr/include/sys
```

but I suppose that only works for an MSYS2 shell? And yet my year old MinGW shell will compile the C code without this error, but despite every effort (following the bash history for package installation for the working version, manually copying over package folders, on and on) I continue to come up against this error. Just copying the folder above into the MinGW include folder results in further issues and is clearly sloppy. I want a repeatable way to get this to work, and I have repeated the process outlined above on several computers and have got the exact same result every time - so I expect anyone starting with a fresh MSYS2 install will run up against the same problems. Any help in getting this to run would be very much appreciated as I am getting frustrated with all of the dead ends.

Comment: Replacing all "x86_64" with "i686" caused `pip install pyinstaller` to fail in the MinGW environment with the same issue coming up in MSYS2.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get this figured out. The first thing to know is that the initial compiling must be done in the MSYS2 shell. Once you successfully compile it in the MSYS2 shell, you can then compile in the MINGW shell without issue. I am not sure why that is so, but I anticipated it would be the case.

I solved the PyInstaller issue by downloading Python 3.7 from http://repo.msys2.org/ and installing it using:

```
pacman -U python-3.7.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar
```

I also needed Python 3.7 installed in Windows, and the path edited in my .bashrc file:

```
export PYTHON_HOME=C:\\Users\\Leigh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37
export PATH="$PYTHON_HOME:$PYTHON_HOME\\Scripts:$PATH"
```

I am not sure if PyInstaller is compatible with Python 3.8 yet. I posted an issue to their GitHub page, and it is here for reference in case it is resolved:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4996

PyInstaller then worked, but I was met with another issue that I posted to Stack Overflow, but figured out as well. That is here:

[MSYS2 gcc fatal error in cc1.exe: cygheap base mismatch detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903833/msys2-gcc-fatal-error-in-cc1-exe-cygheap-base-mismatch-detected/62917371#62917371)

After that issue was resolved I could compile my program in MSYS2. Switching over to a MINGW shell, I found that it now compiled there as well.

Answer (score 0):

`sys/wait.h` isn't there in MinGW, but you can use the one from: https://github.com/win32ports/sys_wait_h

Comment: I don't think this would be very useful, as there are bound to be more system headers that the code will be dependent on outside of wait. There has to be a way to link the MSYS2 headers with the MinGW shell as I already have the latter capable of compiling the C code in Windows. I am just not sure how it was done, and the bash history is not showing anything enlightening.

Comment: @LeighK Believe me, I have ported a lot of stuff to MinGW and a lot of the time you can even leave out `#include <sys/wait.h>` and in some cases the solution is https://github.com/win32ports/sys_wait_h
Yes, many other include files are missing a lot of the time, but usually it's networking stuff like `sys/socket.h` which can usually be replaced by `winsock2.h`.
Porting isn't always easy, but make sure to not mix non-native stuff like Cygwin and MSYS2 sources with native MinGW stuff.