# Netbeans Msys2 make Cygwin1.dll issue

Tags: netbeans, cygwin, msys2

I'm using Netbeans 11 and MSYS2 MINGW64 G++.

Here's a screenshot of my toolchains:

[image]

When I try to run a simple Hello World c++ I get the following errors:

```
     0 [main] cppapplication_2_cygwin_try (19728) D:\Program-Workspaces\netbean
s11\CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try\dist\Debug\MinGW_2-Windows\cppapplication_2_cygw
in_try.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180343408/0x180
347408.                                                                         
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.  
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility            
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*   
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have               
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you          
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
```

In other cases like when using the CLANG++ compiler, everything compiles well with the make.exe.

Could someone help on this please?

Thanks.

EDIT: Adding the NB11 messages:

```
cd 'D:\Program-Workspaces\netbeans11\CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'
D:\Programs\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/D/Programs/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/d/Program-Workspaces/netbeans11/CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'
"/D/Programs/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows/cppapplication_2_cygwin_try.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/d/Program-Workspaces/netbeans11/CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows/main.o.d"
g++ -std=c++2a   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows
g++ -std=c++2a    -o dist/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows/cppapplication_2_cygwin_try build/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows/main.o 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/d/Program-Workspaces/netbeans11/CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/Program-Workspaces/netbeans11/CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17s)

cd 'D:\Program-Workspaces\netbeans11\CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'
D:\Programs\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/D/Programs/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/d/Program-Workspaces/netbeans11/CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'
"/D/Programs/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows/cppapplication_2_cygwin_try.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/d/Program-Workspaces/netbeans11/CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'
make[2]: 'dist/Debug/MinGW_2-Windows/cppapplication_2_cygwin_try.exe' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/d/Program-Workspaces/netbeans11/CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/Program-Workspaces/netbeans11/CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3s)



                                                                                
      0 [main] cppapplication_2_cygwin_try (17884) D:\Program-Workspaces\netbean
s11\CppApplication_2_Cygwin_Try\dist\Debug\MinGW_2-Windows\cppapplication_2_cygw
in_try.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180343408/0x180
347408.                                                                         
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.  
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility            
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*   
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have               
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you          
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.                                          
                                                                                
RUN FAILED (exit value 127, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: One more point worth mentioning is that the compiled program runs fine from a command prompt in Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSYS2 gcc fatal error in cc1.exe: cygheap base mismatch detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903833/msys2-gcc-fatal-error-in-cc1-exe-cygheap-base-mismatch-detected)

Comment: Building is not a problem in NB11. Running it from NB11 is the problem. Added the Build and Run messages to the original post. Please check.

Comment: To me, it looks like a problem with the msys2/usr/bin/make.exe. If I replace that make.exe with some other make, for example, \cygwin64\bin\make.exe, things run fine in NB11!